# How to align a ListView BASELINE in a GridPane

Tags: java, listview, alignment, javafx-8

I'm currently writing a Java-FX program that contains a ListView in a GridPane. I want to align the listview by the baseline of its first item with the label to the left of the listview, but the listview is initially empty. It appears not aligned correctly, but jumps to the right position when it is populated and an item is selected.

I asume, in order to calculate the correct baseline offset, the listview needs to know its items before it is shown. So, how can I create an empty listview and fill it dynamically (by user actions), when it should be aligned BASELINE?

You can reproduce the effect with the following mcve (Java 8 u221):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewAlignmentTest extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        ListView<String> listview = new ListView<String>();
        listview.setPrefSize(100.0, 100.0);

        RowConstraints rc0 = new RowConstraints();
        rc0.setValignment(VPos.BASELINE);

        RowConstraints rc1 = new RowConstraints();
        rc1.setValignment(VPos.BASELINE);

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.getRowConstraints().add(0, rc0);
        root.getRowConstraints().add(1, rc1);
        root.setHgap(10);
        root.setVgap(10);

        root.add(new Label("Some text"), 0, 0);
        root.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
        root.add(new Label("Other text"), 0, 1);
        root.add(listview, 1, 1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);      
        stage.setScene(scene);      
        stage.show();

        listview.getItems().addAll("String1", "String2");
    }
}
```

This is how the GUI looks initially: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVWgb.png

After selecting the first listview item it looks correct: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9432.png

I expect the listview to be aligned BASELINE to the label next to it, but it first appears under the label.

Comment: Trying to align a `ListView` based on any item doesn't make much sense: `ListView` is designed to automatically become scrollable, if enough items are added which would require the position to change when scrolling...

Comment: Yea, it's working fine in Java 12.

Comment: @fabian Comments like yours aren't very useful. Instead of questioning the requirement, it would be better to contribute to a solution.

As long as scrolling is not necessary, a cleanly aligned UI will look much better. In my case, the need for scrolling is very unlikely, so this requirement makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Edit: updated complete code.
When replicated it so that it looks like as shown in image, https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9432.png

Code below makes it immovable.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewAlignmentTest extends Application
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage)
{
    ListView<String> listview = new ListView<String>();
    listview.setPrefSize(100.0, 100.0);

    RowConstraints rc0 = new RowConstraints();
    rc0.setFillHeight(true);

    RowConstraints rc1 = new RowConstraints();
    rc1.setFillHeight(true);

    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    root.getRowConstraints().add(0, rc0);
    root.getRowConstraints().add(1, rc1);
    root.setHgap(10);
    root.setVgap(10);

    root.add(new Label("Some text"), 0, 0);
    root.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
    root.add(new Label("Other text"), 0, 1);
    root.add(listview, 1, 1);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);      
    stage.setScene(scene);      
    stage.show();

    listview.getItems().addAll("String1", "String2");
}
}
```

As a result, it does not move now. That should help.

Comment: I can't reproduce your solution. The listview still appears not aligned and jumps after selecting an item. BTW: Setting vgap to 0 will ruin the look of the UI...

Comment: You removed the requirement for aligning the second label with the first listview item. "Other text" is centered vertically in your screenshot (compare that to my second screenshot). To achieve that, you wouldn't have to set the fillHeight property either.

Comment: My honest intention was to fix the listview's jumping issue that you were concerned about. You are good to go with Java 12. Good Luck!!!